# What is the meaning of "solicited" in "Please do not contact me for any work that is trial / unpaid / solicited"

Tags: meaning-in-context

What is the exact meaning of **solicited** in "Please do not contact me for any work that is trial / unpaid / solicited"?

I have tried dictionary definitions but they don't quite fit the context of this person requesting not to be contacted for unpaid work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that what the individual is saying is that he does not want brokers ("recruiters") to contact him about work they have solicited from a third party.

This is typical of a freelancer website.  Businesses who often need work done on an as-needed contact basis (clients) will get regular contacts from brokers, who are in the business of finding contract work and finding professionals who can do the work.  So, the work itself is solicited by the broker.

So, this advertiser doesn't want to involve a broker, since brokers will attempt to get him to work for about 60% of what he could expect to make negotiating directly with the client (at least, that's the going rate for IT services in the US, with which I'm most familiar).

Answer (score -1):

What this person is almost certainly trying to say is that they don't want *unsolicited* work requests. That is, if they did not solicit (ask for) work from someone, they don't want to be spammed with possibilities out of the blue.

"Solicited" in this context would make no sense. They would be asking for anyone they contact about work to avoid contacting them in reply. And "solicit" is specifically a *polite* word; it implies graciously and professionally asking for something. Lawyers are called "solicitors" in some areas because they must plead a case as convincingly and smoothly as possible.

Comment: But that sentence was found in a freelancer website, where people are supposed to be contacted for work when they (the freelancers) have not solicited any work. Is there any chance that solicited means "asked, in a sort of rude way, to be executed immediately"?

Comment: @aristotle85: No. I've edited to clarify. "Solicit" means basically the opposite of that. (It's possible that the poster of this message you're quoting thought so, but if so, they were quite wrong.)

Comment: @aristotle85: I do appreciate the check mark, but you might want to [wait a bit longer](//meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/1307/not-so-fast-when-should-i-accept-my-answer), just in case.

Comment: No problem, the suggestion to wait actually makes sense.